# How to show $g(t,u)= \frac{f(t,tu)}{t}$ is $C^\infty$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, singularity, smooth-functions

Could you give me a hint:
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a $C^\infty$ function with $f(0,0)=0.$ Define $g(t,u)= f(t,tu)/t$ for $t\neq 0$ and $0$ when $t=0.$  How I will show that $g$ is also $C^\infty$ for $(t,u)\in \mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: I assume you mean $C^\infty$, i.e. the function has all derivatives? (somehow $\mathbb{C}^\infty$ means the Riemann sphere to me)

Comment: @Makuasi, why did you roll back the edit? I was just trying to improve the question's presentation.

Comment: What have you tried? What are you having trouble with? Can you deal with the function away from (0,0)?

Comment: Probably the last $f$ should be $g$

Comment: yes @Daan, Andy:sorry, I did not get.

Comment: Hint: We only need to check whether the derivatives $\partial_t^k g$ exist and are continuous on $\{t=0\}$. You can use induction and just compute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A hint: Consider the auxiliary function
$$\phi(\tau):=f(\tau\, t,\tau\, t u)\qquad(0\leq\tau\leq1)\ $$ and bring $\phi'(\tau)$ into the game.